A preposterous abuse of notation involving Helmholtz decomposition theorem
Take what I am about to present with a light heart, since the mathmetically inclined may find it too out-of-the-world and devastating.

The above diagram (this is drawn by me, but the original is very similar) was presented in one of our lectures today, to showcase the Helmholtz decomposition theorem. The physicist's version of the theorem states:

Let $\mathbf{F} \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)$ be a vector field which decreases faster than $1/r \equiv 1/\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ as $r\to\infty$, then $\mathbf{F}$ can be decomposed into a curl-free and a divergence-free component: $$\mathbf{F}=-\nabla\Phi+\nabla\times\mathbf{A},$$
such that
$$ \Phi = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\mathrm{d}\tau'\frac{\nabla'\cdot\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}')}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|}, $$
$$ \mathbf{A} = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\mathrm{d}\tau'\frac{\nabla'\times\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}')}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|}. $$

This theorem basically says that given a good enough function $\mathbf{F}$, all we need is $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{F}=0$ and $\nabla\times\mathbf{F}$ to uniquely construct the original function. So I suppose the diagram was supposed to say "given the curl and the div, we can surely say there is only one $\mathbf{F}$ (corresponding to its 'coordinate')".
My question is, is there any mathematically insight we could gain from the diagram, or is it just sloppy abuse of notation?

Note that it is not necessary for $\vec\nabla\cdot\vec F=0$. Your diagram is a nice little mental picture of what the theorem essentially conveys: Knowledge of $\vec\nabla\cdot\vec F$ and $\vec\nabla\times\vec F$ everywhere in any region is sufficient to reconstruct the original vector field $\vec F$. To be even more precise, you might need to include surface terms, which might not go to zero even if you send the surface to infinitely far away. There is not much more insight from the diagram than that. Still useful.

while we’re at it, you may want to add an extra axis to indicate suitable boundary conditions on $\vec{F}$ :)

The Helmholtz theorem is not that hard to understand. I would not call the picture an abuse of notation. It is quite nice. However the analogy  with a coordinate system suggests that $\Phi$ and $\mathbf A$ are unique but they are not. Add to $\Phi$ a constant and to $\mathbf A$ a gradient of a scalar function (which is rotation free).
